# Can´t categorize field for unknown reason

Tags: qgis, symbology

I am trying to categorize a field without any success

[image]

The values should be symbolized from 1-5 and yet, I just get that blank symbol.
at first I thought that the problem is that the column is defined as string, so I created a new number column and after updating to the original, I got an NULL column.
Iv'e created another string column and again I got a blank column .
A weird thing is that in the field calculators output preview, the original value appears as it should

[image]

I'm using QGIS 3.4.7 and I have the same issue in other versions as well

here's the way it  looks in the field calculator

[image]

Comment: Did you click 'classify'  in the symbology window?

Comment: @vagvaf Yes I did

Comment: Can you classify with any other attribute? Is this a shapefile or some other data source?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems like it cannot get the Values in Version 3.4.7 but I can get them in version 2.18.17 so, for now I guess I'll stick to that.
I'm using field caculator as shown
[image]

I must say that it's a partial answer so if anyone has a better, I would be glad to hear it

Comment: Do you have two fields with the same name? I can see two fields that start with the word "switch," and the end of both is cut off.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a String to an Integer you can't just copy it (as you see it just can't be done). You want to use the function `to_int(switchboar)` to make the conversion for you.

Comment: Yeah, well I tried it and it also didn't work, I just keep on getting to NULL values. I just think that the fact that it's a string is not the main issue here